# Set max execution time for a magento php command

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I've implemented some custom php commands for magento 2.3 and I've found a weird issue.
The scripts doesn't seem to reset the max_execution time, I've set both from inside the script ( ini_set ) and outside the script ( -d max_execution_time ).

I think there is an ini_set('max_execution_time', 0) somewhere from a Db class, so my settings are overridden.
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: not sure if this is your issue but you can set max_execution_time under php.ini file

Comment: I've tried this already. Seems that the Db class sets the execution time to 0 upon transactions or something...